# Highcharts : display custom images in bars race

Tags: image, highcharts

I use highcharts to create a bars race and it's working well.
The nice to have would be the possibility to add a specific svg image/icon on each bar (related to the category value of the bar). It could be a flag (for coutries), a photo (for persons)...

I made a jsfiddle with an example of bar race here : http://jsfiddle.net/vegaelce/25antjhs/
In this example, I'd like each bar containing on it's rigth, the corresponding flag of the country (URL of the flags are in the "flags" array).

I tried to use derivation of the following code found on other topics without success :

```
function() {
  var chart = this,
    leftOffset = chart.plotLeft,
    topOffset = chart.plotTop,
    series = chart.series[0],
    xAxis = series.xAxis,
    yAxis = series.yAxis,
    points = series.points;

  points.forEach(function(point) {
    var x = xAxis.toPixels(point.x) - leftOffset,
      y = yAxis.toPixels(point.y) - topOffset,
      toCenter = point.shapeArgs.height / 2;

    //toCenter = point.y > 0 ? toCenter : -toCenter;
    toCenter = 0;
    chart.renderer.circle(x, y + toCenter, 10).attr({
      fill: '#BADA55',
      stroke: 'black',
      'stroke-width': 1,
      zIndex: 10
    }).add(series.group);
  });
}
```

Do you have an idea how to do that ?

Comment: Have you tried customizing the official highcharts column comparison demo as a bar series? https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/evscgj0f/

Comment: Yes, it's a first option, result is here : http://jsfiddle.net/vegaelce/hntd3x1q/2/
But what I would like is to get the images/icons not on the X axis but at the end of the bars (image could replace the datalabel or being at the right side, inside the bar, just before datalabel).

Comment: Do you have any idea about how to get images at the right end of the bars instead of on the X axis ? Thanks in advance

Comment: is that a result that you expected? https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/vfdc6qj1/